# Jquery clone div issue

Tags: jquery, clone

I want to clone a div one at a time when i click on a header

```
$("h3").click(function() { $("div").clone().insertAfter("div:last")); });
```

Right now it will clone all the divs and put them after the last one but i want to clone div1 then div2 etc.

Comment: Can you post your html ?

Comment: Is there a relation between the h3 and the div ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use .each() method to get the correct requirement.

```
$("h3").click(function() { 
    $("div").each(function() {
        $this = jQuery(this);
        // do something with current div $this
        $this.clone().insertAfter("div:last"));

        // a bit better?
        $this.parent().prepend($this.clone());
    });
});
```

i hope this help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Try `each`:

```
$("h3").click(function() { 
    $.each($("div"), function() {
        $(this).clone().insertAfter("div:last"); 
    });
});
```